# Laptop screen appears orangish on start up

Tags: laptop, colors

When my laptop starts up, it used to show a white bootup screen with the logo of the manufacturer. Right after that the windows start up screen would show up.

Lately, when I start the computer, the white screen has started to appear more and more yellowish/orangish. This only lasts on the boot screen however, as soon as the windows black background loading screen shows up, the colors are normal and from there on the colors remain normal no matter how long my computer stays on.

It used to be a faint yellowish hue, but last night, it was almost completely orange, a sharp contrast from the white.

What causes this and is this something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the the inverter or the compact fluorescent light (CFL) in the LCD might be failing.  If the laptop is under warranty, it should be covered.

This is possible as a DIY project if you are comfortable taking apart the LCD, otherwise you can get a technician to do it.

Comment: Nah, no warranty, its an old computer. How long would you say its got left, any ideas?

Comment: impossible to say.  could be seconds, could be years.

Comment: Where can I get some instructions on how to do it as a DIY? And around how much might it cost to get a technician to fix it?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S87niyGJfPs  price will be dependent on parts availability

Comment: Google the parts for your laptop model